# Split and join a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column dataframe which has the following structure:

```
Initial-column
--------------
abc:123-456
dsf:231-436
ghi:173-486
jkl:193-156
mnq:120-256
```

I want to obtain the following columns:

```
Index    Name   Coords
----     ----   ----     
 0        abc    123
 1        abc    456
 2        dsf    231
 3        dsf    436
 4        ghi    173
 5        ghi    486
 6        jkl    193
 7        jkl    156
 8        mnq    120
 9        mnq    256
```

I am able to obtain `Name` and `Coords` but in two different columns, but I do not know how to combine them. Any ideas?

```
df[['Name', 'CoordN']] = df['Initial-column'].str.split(':', expand=True)
df[['Coords0', 'Coords1']] = df['CoordN'].str.split('-', expand=True)
```

Comment: df['new'] = df['Name'] + df['Coords0']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage `pd.concat` for that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df.Coords0,df.Coords1])).sort_index()
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Pandas concat concatenates the second output after the first output. What I want to do is to interpolate the results. I want to do something as follows:
`
    s1 = pd.Series(['a', 'b'])
    s2 = pd.Series(['c', 'd'])
    pd.doSomething([s1, s2])
    0    a
    1    c
    2    b
   3    d`

Comment: So you can just sort by the index. I'll add this to the answer

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. I was thinking on something more complex such as zipping and unzipping the results. Thank you very much!